# Development Idea

Tags: security, scripting

I'm developing a solution, that would require users to review and rate certain things in a web page. I need to make sure no user rates a particular thing more than once. Since I'm trying to maintain an anonymous user status, no user information is required of the site users. But how do I go about writing a script or something to prevent users from reviewing a particular item more than once. Please I need ideas. Anyone?

Comment: Have you researched any solutions yourself? Or are you just asking blind here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* potentially use something like a cookie or anonymous user accounts? However, without registering some sort of information tying a user / IP address to a person, it's going to be pretty hard. Cookies could easily be cleared out. And if users sign up (helps keep anonymity by not asking for anything more than a username and password - no emails), then it would still be easy for the user to log out and create a new account. In short, you're not going to have many options for keeping the voting anonymous and yet still limit it to one vote per feature per person, since you have no way to identify "a person".

The only other viable option I could think of was to perhaps hash a user's IP address and use that hash as their "voting token". This token is stored in a cookie or something, and allows them to vote on a feature with their token. You can store the token used and the vote given without storing or gaining access to any of the users data (not even a username or IP)? I'm not sure how viable of an option this would be though - you'd have to brainstorm this one further.

I hope this helps

Comment: yes this helps, would work and brainstorm around your idea. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Think you'll have to lose part of the anonymity... you could use something like IP address maybe? Would not link it to someones specific name.

Comment: But the IP would change by connection to different networks, he might still review the item by connecting to another network. Is der anyoda solution or can u help explain more on yours?

Comment: Upvoted because it's true - you ARE going to have to sacrifice anonymity in some respect if you want to be able to reliably identify "a person"